# Como hacer que los items de un submenu se comiencen a pintar desde donde comienza el menu hasta donde este termina y no debajo del submenu con CSS

Tags: css, css-grid-layout, selectores-css

Mi duda es tengo este componente react y lo que deseo es quie los submenus aparezcan en el mismo lugar es decir como tiene los submenu position: absolute cada vez que doy hover en un menu me aparece su respectivo submenu debajo de ese menu como aparece en la imagen, lo que quiero hacer es que aparezcan en el mismo lugar es decir si hago hover en wathches me aparece el submenu de wathces debajo de este pero quiero hacer hover en smartwatches y que comience a pintarse desde donde comienza watches como logro eso con css

```
<ul className='menu submenu'>
                        {
                            menuNiveltwo.data? 
                            menuNiveltwo.data.map( e => {
                                if(e.category === comparacion){
                                    return(
                                        <li key={e._id} className="item">
                                            <Link to={`/${e.name}`} className="link">
                                                {e.name}
                                            </Link>
                                            {/* <ComponenteMenuNivel3 
                                                url2={url2}
                                                comparacion={e._id}
                                                url3={url3}
                                            /> */}
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                }else{
                                    return null
                                }
                            })
                            : 
                            <div> 
                                Cargando...
                            </div>
                        }
                    </ul>
```

Este es mi css del tanto del menu como del submenu el menu tiene los mismos estilos que los del menu principal no tiene la clase submenu y los items del menu principal no

```
.header{
    width: 100%; 
    background: var(--color_white); 
}
.nav{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.submenu{
    top: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    background: var(--color_white); 
    display:none;
}

.item{
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
}

.item:hover > .submenu{
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 190vh;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20em;
}
.submenu .item:hover > .submenu{
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 20em;
}

.link{
    display:inline-block; 
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem; 
    color: var(--color_negro);
    text-decoration: none; 
    width:100%;
}

.link:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Este es el resultado como se va recorriendo los items de cada menu  lo que quiero es que si hago hover tanto en watches como en gifts
llenen el espacio desde donde comienza watches hasta blog como lo logro con css
[image: Es un ejemplo de un submenu]
[image: Ejemplo del submenu anterior moviendoese]

Lo que quiero es que no se recorra con css
como la pagina real que es esta

https://www.timex.com/

[image: Submenu Recorriendose]

Answer (score 1):

Sí entendí bien tu pregunta, para que el submenu ocupe el 100% del padre, debes de declarar al padre (.menu) con:

```
position: relative;
```

Y al hijo (.submenu) como:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

De esta manera indicamos que la posición absoluta y que empiece a la izquierda, es decir teniendo al padre relativo cogerá a este como referencia.
Así quedará dentro del padre y todos empezarán a la izquierda y no debajo del elemento padre que tienen como referencia.

Te dejo por aquí algo de código que he generado de ejemplo por si pudiera servirte.

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: wheat;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu > li,
.menu > li > .submenu > li {
    list-style: none;

    background-color: tan;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu .submenu {
    display: none;
    background-color: green;
}

.menu li.item:hover > ul.submenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.menu .submenu li {
    background-color: red;
    width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">WATCHES</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 1</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 2</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 3</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 4</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 5</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 6</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 7</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 8</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 9</li>
        <li>WATCHES Submenu 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">SMARTWATCHES</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 1</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 2</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 3</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 4</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 5</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 6</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 7</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 8</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 9</li>
        <li>SMARTWATCHES Submenu 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">CO_LABS</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 1</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 2</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 3</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 4</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 5</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 6</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 7</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 8</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 9</li>
        <li>CO_LABS Submenu 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">GIFTS</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 1</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 2</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 3</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 4</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 5</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 6</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 7</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 8</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 9</li>
        <li>GIFTS Submenu 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">BLOG</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>BLOG Submenu 1</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 2</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 3</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 4</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 5</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 6</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 7</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 8</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 9</li>
        <li>BLOG Submenu 10</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

En Css podemos definir o posicionar elementos html en el DOM con la propiedad position.

**Tipos de posicionamiento**

Un elemento posicionado es un elemento cuyo valor computado de position es relative, absolute, fixed, o sticky. (En otras palabras, cualquiera excepto static).

Ejemplo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

dl > div {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
}

dt {
  background: #B8C1C8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989EA4;
  border-top: 1px solid #717D85;
  color: #FFF;
  font: bold 18px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0 12px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

dd {
  font: bold 20px/45px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

dd + dd {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Andrew W.K.</dd>
    <dd>Apparat</dd>
    <dd>Arcade Fire</dd>
    <dd>At The Drive-In</dd>
    <dd>Aziz Ansari</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>E</dt>
    <dd>Explosions In The Sky</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo &amp; The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```